# GetCharABCWidths() and GetGlyphOutline() return FALSE. Why?

Tags: windows, winapi

There seems to be a bug in the GetCharABCWidths() and GetGlyphOutline() functions, when the font size is changed from (-16 * i) / 72, to (-n * i) /72 , for any n below 16.

The character 'a' is still displayed correctly but the functions return FALSE and GDI_ERROR.
Why ???

GetLastError() for GetCharABCWidths() returns 0 (ERROR_SUCCESS) and for
GetGlyphOutline() GetLastError() returns 1003 (CANNOT COMPLETE FUNCTION).

```
MAT2 gmat = { {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1} };


case WM_PAINT:

        PAINTSTRUCT ps;

        BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        int i;

        i = GetDeviceCaps(ps.hdc, LOGPIXELSY);

        LOGFONT lf;

        memset(&lf, 0, sizeof(LOGFONT));
        lf.lfHeight = (-14 * i) / 72;
        lf.lfWeight = FW_NORMAL;
        lf.lfItalic = 0;
        lf.lfCharSet = SYMBOL_CHARSET;
        wcscpy(lf.lfFaceName, L"Symbol");

        HFONT hFont;

        hFont = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
        hFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(ps.hdc, hFont);

        BOOL bx;
        ABC abc;
        TCHAR tx;
        DWORD dwx;

        tx = 'a';

        if( !GetCharABCWidths(ps.hdc, tx, tx, &abc) ) dwx = GetLastError();

        GLYPHMETRICS gm;

        if( GetGlyphOutline(ps.hdc, tx, GGO_METRICS, &gm, 0, NULL, &gmat) == GDI_ERROR )
            dwx = GetLastError();

        TextOut(ps.hdc, 10, 20, (LPTSTR)&tx, 1);

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
```

Comment: If you read the MSDN and it does NOT say that you can call GetLastError() it is nonsense to call it. Generally GDI functions do not support GetLastError() !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my system, Symbol exists both as a raster font (`symbole.fon`) and an OpenType font (`symbol.ttf`), so when GDI decides to use the raster version of the font you won't be able to obtain any TrueType metrics. To fix this, set the `fdwOutputPrecision` member of your `LOGFONT` to something suitable, such as `OUT_TT_PRECIS`.

Comment: That was perfect. The functions are working now with n = 14. Could you explain why they were working before only for n >= 16 ?

Comment: @jaayrosa My raster font provides sizes of 8, 10, 12, 14, 18, 24. So I would have expected your code to fail for those six values. But I don't know for sure what algorithm GDI uses to choose between the fonts.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. How do I know the fonts installed on my system ?

Comment: @jaayrosa I just looked under Fonts in Control Panel.